# Senha Touch complex Model with XTemplate in List

Tags: list, templates, model, sencha-touch

I'm parsing a relatively complex JSON file, but having troubles when rendering it in a list.

An excerpt of (a stripped down version of) the JSON is this:

```
{"root":[
  {
     "success":"true",
     "text":"Vecka 2, 14 januari 2011",
     "chart":[
        {
           "pbpl":"1",
           "arso":"JAY SMITH",
           "tit":"JAY SMITH",
           "labl":"COLUMBIA",
           "buyExt":[
              {
                 "storeId":"61002",
                 "buyPri":"100",
                 "buyURL":"http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=46&a=1861394&url=http%3A%5C%5Ccdon.se%5Cmusik%5Csmith_jay%5Cjay_smith-13014585"
              },
              {
                 "storeId":"61010251",
                 "buyPri":"130",
                 "buyURL":"http://www.bengans.se/Product.aspx?skivkod=882785"
              },
           ]
        },
        {
           "pbpl":"2",
           "arso":"ROBYN",
           "tit":"BODY TALK PT.2",
           "labl":"KONICHIWA RECORDS",
           "buyExt":[
              {
                 "storeId":"61002",
                 "buyPri":"100",
                 "buyURL":"http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=46&a=1861394&url=http%3A%5C%5Ccdon.se%5Cmusik%5Crobyn%5Cbody_talk_pt.2-11318544"
              },
              {
                 "storeId":"61010251",
                 "buyPri":"130",
                 "buyURL":"http://www.bengans.se/Product.aspx?skivkod=870725"
              },
           ]
        },
        ...
```

This is the model:

```
Ext.regModel('Chart', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'text', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'chart', fields: [
            {name: 'arso', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'tit', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'pbpl', type: 'integer'}
        ]}
    ]
});
```

The template I'm using is this:

```
app.chartItemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for="chart">',
    '   <div class="thumb-wrap chart_row" id="{#}">',
    '       <table>',
    '           <tr>',
    '               <td class="chart_pbpl">{#}</td>',
    '               <td class="chart_album">',
    '                   <span class="arso">{arso}</span><br />',
    '                   <span class="tit">{tit}</span><br />',
    '               </td>',
    '           </tr>',
    '       </table>',
    '   </div>',
    '   <div style="clear: both"></div>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

The problem is that is does not create an element for every "chart" entry.
Instead, it creates only one list item, but loops the "chart" entries inside it, rendering a huge sole item.

The store is this:

```
Ext.regStore('ChartsStore', {
    model: 'Chart',
    proxy: {
        type: 'scripttag',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'root'
        }
    },
    getGroupString: function (record) {
        if (record && record.data.text) {
            return record.get('text');
        } else {
            return 'No description';
        }
    }
});
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thanks,
Arttie

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a List you need to provide Template for one individual list item not for the whole list, i.e. not looping through all the chart elements, only the template for one such element. If your list's store is correctly set up, then just remove the `'<tpl for="chart">'` and `'</tpl>'` and the template would work. The list itself applies the looping through it's elements.

Comment: Thanks for answering, ilija139.
If I remove the tpl tags, it presents only a broken item without the chart entries.
I believe the problem is that I want to loop "chart", that is a deeper node.
Any other ideas/examples, please?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** My answer is based on Sencha Touch 2.3.0.

What you are trying to do here looks a bit confusing. Normally, you would set a `rootProperty`  (not `root`) on your `proxie`'s `reader` that points to the object inside your JSON that contains the all the objects to be put on a list, or , in other words, to iterate on. In this case, something like `rootProperty: 'root[0].charts'`, taking into account that you don't use the field `text` which is outside the object `charts` on your JSON.

Then, your model would be something like this, taking into account that you need `arso` and `tit`. You could use `pbpl` to replace the `#` value, since your XTemplate won't be needing a Loop.

```
Ext.regModel('Chart', {
    fields: [
        "pbpl",
        "arso",
        "tit",
       ]
    ]
});
```

Your XTemplate would be:

```
app.chartItemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate([
    '   <div class="thumb-wrap chart_row" id="{pbpl}">',
    '       <table>',
    '           <tr>',
    '               <td class="chart_pbpl">{pbpl}</td>',
    '               <td class="chart_album">',
    '                   <span class="arso">{arso}</span><br />',
    '                   <span class="tit">{tit}</span><br />',
    '               </td>',
    '           </tr>',
    '       </table>',
    '   </div>',
    '   <div style="clear: both"></div>'].join();
);
```

*See how I made an array and used the method `array.join()` to merge it all into one string.*

And your store would be:

```
Ext.regStore('ChartsStore', {
    model: 'Chart',
    proxy: {
        type: 'json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'root[0].chart' // For some reason, root is an "array", that's why the "[0]". No sure if this works on Sencha Touch 2.3.0.
        }
    },
    getGroupString: function (record) {
        if (record && record.data.text) {
            return record.get('text');
        } else {
            return 'No description';
        }
    }
});
```

*I've changed the `proxy`'s `type` to `json`, since I couldn't find the type `scripttag` on Sencha Touch 2.3 Documentation.*

I  know this is a pretty old question, but I felt like answering it.